# How to predict an outcome of the game (next row) based on all previous games (rows)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, data-transformation

I'm a data science student and I've come across a fairly unusual dataset (to me, which explains the vague title).

It's of the following form:

| STAT_1 | STAT_2 | ... | HOME | AWAY | NEXT_HOME | NEXT_AWAY | NEXT_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 11 | ... | Team A | Team B | Team C | Team D | 1 |
| 11 | 18 | ... | Team C | Team D | Team E | Team F | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10 | 11 | ... | Team W | Team X | Team Y | Team Z | 1 |

Basically, the rows represent the statistics of the "current" match and at the end of the row the columns NEXT_HOME and NEXT_AWAY represent the teams which are playing the next game (next row) and the result of that next game is stored in NEXT_WINNER.

The test data is of the same form but without the NEXT_WINNER column because that's the target variable.

This is unusual to me because essentially I need to predict the outcome of the next match based on all previous matches using a machine learning model of my choice.

I've never done anything like this so I would appreciate some guidance (not solutions, just advice and where to start). Something of the sort of how to transform the dataset to make it more manageable. I'm guessing I should somehow store stats for each team and do something with it but I'm unsure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create some variables representing the history of games. For example, a variable could be number of matches that were played before this match. Percentage of home wins up until this match. You could use frequency of win for each team as a variable and add them as separate columns for each home and away. I would start from here, develop models, and see which of these contributed to it.

Comment: Oh, so each row would basically contain stats from all rows before it in some average/median/count fashion and then I'd train the model on those variables? I suppose the test set would contain these same variables as well so the model could be evaluated? Did I understand correctly? Also, thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. The goal is to make data structure independent from the problem structure. No problem